# Feature update to Windows 10, version 20H2 - Error 0x80070002

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am not able to update my desktop Windows. I tried to follow this tutorial https://www.ionos.co.uk/digitalguide/server/configuration/0x80070002-error/, but nothing worked. Any idea what else could help?

Thank you

[image: error]

EDIT:
Results of the solutions from above link:

Solution 1: Check the System Date and Time

- time synced and is OK

Solution 2: Restart the Windows Update Service

- tried running the update with all possible states of the service

Solution 3: Check and Repair System Files

- everything OK

Solution 4: Check the Windows Drive for File System Errors

- everything OK

Solution 5: Use the Update Troubleshooter

- update failed - see screenshots below

Solution 6: Check the System for Malware

- no malware detected as far as I am aware

Solution 7: Manually Install the Problematic Update

- online catalog doesn't work for me

EDIT:
When I tried a manual update it ended up following error even when I have more like 500GB free space on my C drive (SSD)...

[image: error2]

[image: error3]

Comment: What were the results of each of the steps on the linked site?

Comment: @Tetsujin I updated the question text. Thanks

Comment: Please run SetupDiag and provide the output.  Additionally, what version are you currently on?  This must not be a new issue if your build isn’t receiving updates.  Feature updates have never been on the update catalog

Answer (score 0):

The error 0x80070002 commonly means file not found.

Since (above solutions 1 to 7) you have tried numerous basic steps, the best solution now is to do a Windows 10 Repair Install and then try updating again.

Start with the first method:  Keep Everything. Make sure important documents are backed up just to be sure.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

(1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

(2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost.

(3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.

I have done repair installs and the results are always positive.

Here is a supporting article about this issue.

[Windows 10 20H2 Update Error](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/jlppw4/keep_getting_error_0x80070002_when_updating_to/)

Comment: Thank you. I followed your tutorial, but I wasn't asked how should the upgdate proceed (1,2,3). The setup ended the same way as before. It says it can't tell if my PC has enough space to continue installing Windows 10. Again and again... :(

Comment: Please move document files off the computer temporarily to a USB drive to save space. Then run Admin Tools, Disk Cleanup and select Clean up System Files to save space. You need to regain about 30 GB of free space.

Comment: But I have like 500GB free of space

Comment: You may need to use Option 3 in the answer above:  Back everything up, Keep Nothing, and then reinstall. I am not sure what other approach might work.